# SharePoint Online Get selected list items based on multiple IDs - Unmanaged CSOM / JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to retrieve set of list items based on selected IDs. Is there a way to retrieve in single shot by passing array of IDs? using unmanaged CSOM/JSOM/REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('List Title');
var itemIds = [1, 2, 56, 90, 108 ];
var items = [];  
itemIds.forEach(function(itemId){
    var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
    context.load(item);
    items.push(item);
});
context.executeQueryAsync(
  function() {
     items.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item.get_item('Title')); 
     });
  },
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```